# What is the best way to slurp a file into a string in Perl?

Tags: perl, string, file-io, file

Yes, [There's More Than One Way To Do It](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There_is_more_than_one_way_to_do_it) but there must be a canonical or most efficient or most concise way. I'll add answers I know of and see what percolates to the top.

To be clear, the question is how best to read the contents of a file into a string.
One solution per answer.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

How about this:

```
use File::Slurp;
my $text = read_file($filename);
```

ETA: note [Bug #83126 for File-Slurp: Security hole with encoding(UTF-8)](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=83126). I now recommend using [File::Slurper](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Slurper) (disclaimer: I wrote it), also because it has better defaults around encodings:

```
use File::Slurper 'read_text';
my $text = read_text($filename);
```

or [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny):

```
use Path::Tiny;
path($filename)->slurp_utf8;
```

Comment: What if you don't want this to die if the file doesn't exist?

Comment: The easiest way to prevent that from being likely is that simply first checking if the file exists...

Comment: this does have the disadvantage that it is not included in out-of-the-box perl. at least not my ActiveState perl for windows (v5.10.0).

Comment: Note that File::Slurp has recently been discovered to be a huge security problem: https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=83126

Comment: Hi, I got `Undefined subroutine &main::read_text`. It should be `use File::Slurper 'read_text';`. https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Slurper

Comment: File::Slurp isn't a portable solution. On Windows, it will barf on all non-ANSI filenames. I haven't tested Path::Tiny, but given Perl's general level of contempt for Windows, I'll bet that it's the same. It may be possible to open a file with Win32::LongPath and pass the filehandle instead of the filepath. (That's something that Perl really should support in all file I/O,)

Answer (score 48):

I like doing this with a `do` block in which I localize `@ARGV` so I can use the diamond operator to do the file magic for me.

```
 my $contents = do { local(@ARGV, $/) = $file; <> };
```

If you need this to be a bit more robust, you can easily turn this into a subroutine.

<s>If you need something really robust that handles all sorts of special cases, use [File::Slurp](http://search.cpan.org/dist/File-Slurp). Even if you aren't going to use it, take a look at the source to see all the wacky situations it has to handle.</s> [File::Slurp](http://search.cpan.org/dist/File-Slurp) has a [big security problem](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=83126) that doesn't look to have a solution. Part of this is its failure to properly handle encodings. Even my quick answer has that problem. If you need to handle the encoding (maybe because you don't make everything UTF-8 by default), this expands to:

```
my $contents = do {
    open my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $file or die '...';
    local $/;
    <$fh>;
    };
```

If you don't need to change the file, you might be able to use [File::Map](http://www.metacpan.org/module/File::Map).

Comment: I'm lazy and write `my $contents = do {local (@ARGV,$/) = $file; <>};`, which is the exact same thing in less characters :)

Comment: I'm wondering why local @ARGV = $file; <> would be any different than <$file>.

Comment: @Bemrose: because $file is not a filehandle.

Comment: I got shot in the foot adding this method to a file that further down was already using `<>`, expecting it to read from `STDIN`. The behaviour of `<>` differs from the first call to subsequent calls, and since I changed the first call, I altered the behaviour of the existing call too (which was expecting the `<STDIN>` behaviour of `<>`).

Answer (score 35):

In writing [File::Slurp](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Slurp) (which is the best way), Uri Guttman did a lot of research in the many ways of slurping and which is most efficient.  He wrote down [his findings here](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/File-Slurp-9999.13/extras/slurp_article.pod) and incorporated them info File::Slurp.

Comment: Note that File::Slurp has recently been discovered to be a huge security problem: https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=83126

Answer (score 24):

```
open(my $f, '<', $filename) or die "OPENING $filename: $!\n";
$string = do { local($/); <$f> };
close($f);
```

Answer (score 11):

Things to think about (especially when compared with other solutions):

1. Lexical filehandles
2. Reduce scope
3. Reduce magic

So I get:

```
my $contents = do {
  local $/;
  open my $fh, $filename or die "Can't open $filename: $!";
  <$fh>
};
```

I'm not a big fan of magic <> except when actually using magic <>.  Instead of faking it out, why not just use the open call directly?  It's not much more work, and is explicit.  (True magic <>, especially when handling "-", is far more work to perfectly emulate, but we aren't using it here anyway.)

Comment: And in case it's not obvious to those following along at home, at the end of the curly block, $fh goes out of scope and the file handle is closed automatically.

Answer (score 10):

mmap (Memory mapping) of strings may be useful when you:

- Have very large strings, that you don't want to load into memory

  Want a blindly fast initialisation (you get gradual I/O on access)

  Have random or lazy access to the string.

  May want to update the string, but are only extending it or replacing characters:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings; use strict;

use IO::File;
use Sys::Mmap;

sub sip {

    my $file_name = shift;
    my $fh;

    open ($fh, '+<', $file_name)
        or die "Unable to open $file_name: $!";

    my $str;

    mmap($str, 0, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, $fh)
      or die "mmap failed: $!";

    return $str;
}

my $str = sip('/tmp/words');

print substr($str, 100,20);
```

**Update: May 2012**

The following should be pretty well equivalent, after replacing [Sys::Mmap](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Sys-Mmap/) with [File::Map](http://search.cpan.org/dist/File-Map/)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings; use strict;

use File::Map qw{map_file};

map_file(my $str => '/tmp/words', '+<');

print substr($str, 100, 20);
```

Comment: Actually, File::Map (disclaimer: written by me) would be a better choice nowadays. It's far more portable (it works on both Unix and Windows), but also easier to use («map_file my $str, $file_name;»).

Answer (score 8):

This is neither fast, nor platform independent, and really evil, but it's short (and I've seen this in Larry Wall's code ;-):

```
 my $contents = `cat $file`;
```

Kids, don't do that at home ;-).

Answer (score 8):

```
use Path::Class;
file('/some/path')->slurp;
```

Answer (score 7):

```
{
  open F, $filename or die "Can't read $filename: $!";
  local $/;  # enable slurp mode, locally.
  $file = <F>;
  close F;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
use IO::All;

# read into a string (scalar context)
$contents = io($filename)->slurp;

# read all lines an array (array context)
@lines = io($filename)->slurp;
```

Answer (score 6):

For one-liners you can usually use [the `-0` switch](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-0*%5b_octal%2fhexadecimal_%5d) (with `-n`) to make perl read the whole file at once (if the file doesn't contain any null bytes):

```
perl -n0e 'print "content is in $_\n"' filename
```

If it's a binary file, you could use `-0777`:

```
perl -n0777e 'print length' filename
```

Comment: Makes for a nice way to check that an attempted line substitution in a file actually happens: perl -p -i -0 -e 's/^old_line/new_line/m or (print and die)' some_file, or probably could use /mg to do all matching lines if many expected.

Answer (score 4):

See the summary of [Perl6::Slurp](https://metacpan.org/module/Perl6::Slurp) which is incredibly flexible and generally does the right thing with very little effort.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a nice comparison of the most popular ways to do it:

http://poundcomment.wordpress.com/2009/08/02/perl-read-entire-file/

Comment: Link only answer as discouraged. Copy the code into your answer

Answer (score 3):

Nobody said anything about read or sysread, so here is a simple and fast way:

```
my $string;
{
    open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";
    read $fh, $string, -s $file;   # or sysread
    close $fh;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Candidate for the worst way to do it!  (See comment.)

```
open(F, $filename) or die "OPENING $filename: $!\n";
@lines = <F>;
close(F);
$string = join('', @lines);
```

Comment: This is probably the most inefficient way I can think of, especially for large files.  Now you have two copies of the same data and you have processed it twice just to load it into a scalar.

Comment: It's all situational.  For a small file or a run-only-once quickie script, where "$string=`cat $filename`" is not available, this is perfectly reasonable.  Inefficient yes!  But that's not necessarily the only consideration.

Comment: This answer doesn't deserve a negative rating. Bunch of script kiddies that don't understand or care about what perl means by <FILEHANDLE>. It's an array silly. No worse performance than some of the other answers on this page. Very informative on how to think about Perl filehandles and slurping, as an array.

Answer (score 1):

Adjust the special record separator variable `$/`

```
undef $/;
open FH, '<', $filename or die "$!\n";
my $contents = <FH>;
close FH;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
open(IN, "<$filename");
$contents = join('', <IN>);
close(IN);
```

Details:

`<IN>` is a file descriptor returns a list (aka array) of lines if assigned to an list variable/context.

`join` takes a delimiter and a list of lines and returns a string with all the lines joined together. Source: https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join).

`open` with a filename prefix of "<" opens the file in read-mode.

I use the join construct often for slurping one-liners eg `perl -e '$_=join("",<>);s/multiline_regex/replacement_string/gms;print'`. m/s options support multiline regexs, see https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).