# How to implement a regex pattern into whole file not line by line?

Tags: regex, perl

How can I read from am file and find the matched patterns into a file not line by line to whole file at one time with Perl?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206661/what-is-the-best-way-to-slurp-a-file-into-a-string-in-perl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the whole file into a string, by adding the `local $/;` handle to the beginning of the perl script before reading the file. They you can apply your regex to the resulting string.

Once you build the long `$string` which contains the whole file, you can find all the matches as follows:

```
@matches = $string =~ m/\s*rem/gi;
```

Comment: For example my string variable is $string, and my regex patter is m/\s*rem/i so how can I find all the matched string according to that pattern and if possible while writing it to output putting a newline - \n after every matched string?

Comment: For matching all, you need to add `g` modifier. Do your matching like this: `@matches = $string =~ m/\s*rem/gi;`

Comment: How can I remove newline characters with modifying my pattern?

Comment: substitute all the newlines with blank `$string =~ s/\n*//g;`

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old, but I was faced with the same problem and found the answer to be simpler than the chosen answer.
Using '-0777' (or anything larger than -0400) toghether with -p or -n after the perl executable will change the default separator and perl will slurp the whole file into $_

References:

- https://riptutorial.com/perl/example/16725/slurp-file-in-one-liner
- https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html