# Open file reads only one line

Tags: perl, file

I have an issue with file reading in `perl`.

There is a following source:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub main()
{
    my @lines = file_read("test.c") or die;
    file_print(@lines);
}

sub file_read
{
    my $filename = shift;
    my @lines;

    open(FILE, "<", $filename) or die $!;
    @lines = <FILE>;
    return @lines;
}

sub file_print
{
    my @lines = shift();

    print("Total lines " . scalar(@lines) . "\n");

    foreach my $line (@lines)
    {
            print($line);
    }
}
```

And the following file:

```
/******************************************************************************

*                                                                             *

*                                                                             *
```

The output is:

```
Total lines 1
/******************************************************************************
```

What is wrong here?

The only thing that I can suppose that it reads file till `0x0A 0x0A` `ASCII` symbols combination.

Comment: take a look at `File::Slurp` (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/206682/180100)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code shown is not the full or correct Perl program, nothing shown actually calls `main`. Also the sequence

```
my @lines;
open(FILE, "<", $filename) or die $!;
file_print(@lines);
@lines = <FILE>;
```

tries to print the lines before reading them.

I think the reason that only one line appears to have been read is in the statement `my @lines = shift();`. This does not get the whole array, only its first element. Try replacing `sub file_print{...}` with

```
sub file_print
{
    print("Total lines " . scalar(@_) . "\n");

    foreach my $line (@_)
    {
            print($line);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't know how could I miss it.

Comment: `print @_` actually does exactly the same thing as your foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably pass an array reference for the subroutine `file_print`

```
file_print(\@lines);
```

Then in the subroutine :

```
$lines = shift;
@lines = @$lines;
```

This will do the job.