# How to use newline in substitution s/// in RE using Perl?

Tags: perl

Input file contains more than 1 newlines, empty tags as follows:

```
<html>
<body>
<title>XXX</title>
<p>text...</p>
<collaboration seq="">
<ce:text></ce:text>
</collaboration>
...


<p>text</p>
<collaboration seq="">
<ce:text>AAA</ce:text>
</collaboration>
<p>text</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Output file needed with only one newline characters, empty tags must be removed

```
<html>
<body>
<title>XXX</title>
<p>text...</p>
...
<p>text</p>  
<p>text</p>
<collaboration seq="">
<ce:text>AAA</ce:text>
</collaboration>
</body>
</html>
```

Coding which in have tried:

```
print "Enter the file name without extension: ";
chomp($filename=<STDIN>);
open(RED,"$filename.txt") || die "Could not open TXT file";
open(WRIT,">$filename.html");
while(<RED>)
{
  #process in file
  s/<collaboration seq="">\n<ce:text><\/ce:text>\n<\/collaboration>//g;
  s/\n\n//g;
  print WRIT $_;
}
close(RED);
close(WRIT);
```

Above coding doesn't clears anything which is needed... How to solve this?

Comment: Your script works line by line, so you can not match multiple line. And if you have a string with the whole thext you need the /m flag for multiline match.

Comment: @Jens: `/m` just changes what `^` and `$` match.

Comment: try this:  s/^$//m;
           print WRIT $_;

Answer (score 0):

First you should actually slurp the file. so let's say that you use [zigdon's method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/206683/2642059):

```
my $file;
{
    print "Enter the file name without extension: ";
    my $filename = <STDIN>

    chomp($filename);
    open F, $filename or die "Can't read $filename: $!";
    local $/;  # enable slurp mode, locally.
    $file = <F>;
    close F;
}
```

Now `$file` contains the contents of your file so you can work with it.

```
#process in file
$file ~= s/<collaboration seq="">\R<ce:text><\/ce:text>\R<\/collaboration>//g;
$file ~= s/\R{2,}/\n/g; #I'm guessing this is probably what you intended
print WRIT $file;
```

Comment: don't parse HTML/XML with regular expressions. ever.

Comment: @PatrickJ.S. I'd generally agree with that comment, because Perl does have a lot of good xml extensions. However, that's a separate question and serves only to unnecessarily obscure what should be a simple answer here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XML::Simple for this:

```
# use XML simple to process the XML
my $xs = XML::Simple->new(
      # remove extra whitespace
      NormaliseSpace => 2,
      # keep root element
      KeepRoot       => 1,
      # force elements to arrays
      ForceArray     => 1,
      # ignore empty elements
      SuppressEmpty  => 1
);
# read in the XML
my $ref = $xs->XMLin($xml);


# print out the XML minus the empty tags
print $xs->XMLout($ref);
```