# Holding files in memory in perl while using them like file handles

Tags: perl, file, io

I have a script in perl that I need to modify. The script opens, reads and seeks through two large (ASCII) files (they are several GB in size). Since it does that quite a bit, I would like to put these two files completely into RAM. The easiest way of doing this while not modifying the script a lot would be to load the files into the memory in a way that I can treat the resulting variable just as a file handle - and for example use seek to get to a specific byte position. Is that possible in perl?

Update: Using File::Slurp as proposed does the job only for small files. If the files are larger than about 2GB, it doesn't work.

Mimimum example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Tie::File;
use File::Slurp 'read_file';

my $fn="testfile";

#buffer, then open as file, read first line:
read_file($fn, buf_ref => \my $file_contents_forests) or die "Could not read file!";
my $filehandle;
open($filehandle, "<", \$file_contents_forests) or die "Could not open buffer: $!\n";
my $line = "the first line:".<$filehandle>;
print $line."\n";
close($filehandle);

#open as file, read first line:
open( FORESTS,  "<",$fn) or die "Could not open file.\n";
my $line = "the first line:".<FORESTS>;
print $line;
close(FORESTS);
```

The output in this case is identical for the two methods if the file size is < 2 GB. If the file is larger, then slurping returns an empty line.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Nice! And how is it possible?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/206778/223226

Comment: You can test how large strings you can store in memory using  `Number::Bytes::Human::size` and `Devel::Size::size` : On my laptop I can go up to around 4 GB... For example: `print format_bytes(size("1" x 3_100_000_000)) . "\n";` gives 2.9G..

Comment: I get 2.9 GB as well. I think that the memory buffer is okay, is just using it as a file handle that fails.

Answer (score 5):

Read in the file:

```
use File::Slurp 'read_file';
read_file( "filename", buf_ref => \my $file_contents );
```

and open a filehandle to it:

```
open my $file_handle, '<', \$file_contents;
```

Comment: To make the code backward compatible with Perl earlier than 5.8, use `IO::String` module..

Comment: So this works for me in principle, but unfortunately it does not work for large files (>2 GB). In this case, $file_contents holds the contents of the file, but <$file_handle> returns an empty variable. Is there a way around this?