# Compare multiline strings in bash variables

Tags: string, bash, pipe

I have a script with two multiline strings. I'd like to know if they are equal. I haven't found a way to do this, because while comparing is easy, passing the value of the variables to the comparison thingamajig isn't. I haven't had success piping it to diff, but it could be my ineptitude (many of the things I've tried resulted in 'File name too long' errors). A workaround would be to replace newlines by some rare character, but it meets much the same problem. Any ideas?

Comment: try this: `diff <(echo "$string1") <(echo "$string2")`

Comment: Hi! That gives me `syntax error near unexpected token '(':         diff <(echo "$S1") <(echo "$S2")'`. Note: this is OS X, but I'm not sure that's the problem.

Comment: I should point out that my bash (3.2.57) doesn't seem to support the `<(...)` syntax, regardless of what's inside. I know I tagged this with 'bash', but if possible I'd like a generic answer (though any answer at all would be helpful!),

Comment: `I have a script with two multiline strings.` Would you mind posting the script?

Comment: Are you using `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/sh`?

Comment: You can check question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31540902/how-to-check-if-one-file-is-part-of-other

Comment: `bash` 3.2 absolutely supports process substitution, but not if it is run as `sh`.

Comment: @Will and @chepner, you were right. Changing to `#!/bin/bash` made @ritesht93's `diff` work. What should I do regarding the question now?

Comment: I would use `diff <(echo "$string1") <(echo "$string2")` or `cmp <(echo "$string1") <(echo "$string2")`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might be helpful:

```
var=$(echo -e "this\nis \na\nstring" | md5sum)
var2=$(echo -e "this\nis not\na\nstring" | md5sum)
if [[ $var == $var2 ]] ; then echo true; else echo false; fi
```

Comment: 1. You better use ${} in stead of $(). 2. You don't need to use md5sum... you can just compare the strings "as is"

Comment: @I-V `${...}` cannot be used in place of `$(...)`. You are right about `md5sum`, though.

Comment: Why not {}?  (I really want to understand :) )

Comment: @I-V `${var}` is variable expansion, `$(date)` is command substitution.

Comment: Yes, this can probably be done directly. However, the OP mentions a problem passing the multi-line strings to a comparison. What is that problem exactly?

Comment: I'm accepting this one as it seems to work with `#!/bin/sh`. Without that restriction, plain diff works, as discussed in the question comments.

Answer (score 7):

Even if you're using `sh` you absolutely can compare multiline strings. In particular there's no need to hash the strings with `md5sum` or another similar mechanism.

Demo:

```
$ cat /tmp/multiline.sh
#!/bin/sh

foo='this
is
a
string'

bar='this
is not
the same
string'
    
[ "$foo" = "$foo" ]  && echo SUCCESS || echo FAILURE
[ "$foo" != "$bar" ] && echo SUCCESS || echo FAILURE

$ /tmp/multiline.sh
SUCCESS
SUCCESS
```

In `bash` you can (and [generally should](https://stackoverflow.com/q/669452/5765873)) use `[[ ... ]]` instead of `[ ... ]`, but they both still support multiline strings.

Comment: But hey! Both the Equal and Not-equal comparison return the same `SUCCESS` here. I guess something is wrong.

Comment: @saulius2 They're comparing different values - `$var = $var` vs. `$var != $var2`. The "SUCCESS" indicates the comparison (equals or not-equals) behaved correctly.

Comment: Thanks! Missed that `2` is omitted from the first line.

Answer (score 4):

Working with [`bats`](https://github.com/bats-core/bats-core) and [`bats-assert`](https://github.com/ztombol/bats-assert) I sued the solution from [@dimo414](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49551706/802365) (upvote his answer)

```
@test "craft a word object" {
  touch "$JSON_FILE"
  entry=$(cat <<-MOT
  {
    "key": "bonjour",
    "label": "bonjour",
    "video": "video/bonjour.webm"
  },
MOT
)

  run add_word "bonjour"

  content=$(cat $JSON_FILE)
  assert_equal "$entry" "$content"
}
```