# perl: concatenate lines into a single string

Tags: perl

I have a file that looks something like this:

```
hellothisisline1
andthisisline2hi
yepthisistheline
```

I want to concatenate the lines so that into a single string

`hellothisisline1andthisisline2hiyepthisistheline`

```
print "Input file name \n";
open (FILE, <>);
$string = "";
while($line = <FILE>) {
   $string = $string . "" . $line;
}
print "$string \n";
```

But that didn't seem to work and the output is the file in its original format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to slurp a file into a string in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206661/what-is-the-best-way-to-slurp-a-file-into-a-string-in-perl)

Comment: $ perl -lne '$all .= $_; END {print $all}' yourfile.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Perl5, `chomp` is useful to remove the newline character at the end of string.

```
print "Input file name \n";
open (FILE, <>);
$string = ""; 
while($line = <FILE>) {
    chomp($line); # add this line
    $string = $string . "" . $line;
}
print "$string \n";
```

Answer (score -1):

Using the [chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) function to remove the newlines.
The map applies the [chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) function to each line, and the join sticks all the lines together.

```
print "Input file name \n";
open (FILE, <>);
$string = join('', map { chomp; $_ } <FILE>);
print "$string \n";
```

Could also use "tr" to delete the newlines after slurping the file:

```
print "Input file name \n";
open (FILE, <>);
($string = join('', <FILE>)) =~ tr/\n//d;
print "$string \n";
```

Comment: Yes, in general, but chomp needs something to work on.. The map gives the context to read from <FILE> into $_ which the chomp can work on. You could read into a separate temporary array and chomp that if you wanted... just uglier.