# Read address from another file using Perl

Tags: perl

I'm trying to create a script that will read URL from another file. My first step is a creation of the file with my URL:

```
cat > address.txt
https://unix.stackexchange.com
```

Then I create perl-script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use LWP::Simple;
$content = get($URL);
die "Couldn't get it!" unless defined $content;
```

What should I do to set address from address.txt instead of $URL in my script?

Comment: Have you tried just reading from file ? Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206661/what-is-the-best-way-to-slurp-a-file-into-a-string-in-perl ?

Comment: The question lists many ways to read from file. For example
 open F, $filename or die "Can't read $filename: $!";
  $file = <F>;
  close F;

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume that the file will always only have one line in it...

First, always put `use warnings;` and `use strict;` at the top of your scripts. This catches the most common and basic problems before you even get going (like not declaring your variables with `my` for instance).

You need to [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) the file (using the three-argument form, and catching any errors with `die`), then you need to assign the line in the file to a variable, then [chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) off any newline character.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use LWP::Simple;

my $file = 'address.txt';

open my $fh, '<', $file
  or die "can't open the $file file!: $!";

my $url = <$fh>;
chomp $url;

my $content = get($url);
die "Couldn't get it!" unless defined $content;
```