# What is the Perl's IO::File equivalent to open($fh, ">:utf8",$path)?

Tags: perl, utf-8

It's possible to white a file utf-8 encoded as follows:

```
open my $fh,">:utf8","/some/path" or die $!;
```

How do I get the same result with IO::File, preferably in 1 line?
I got this one, but does it do the same and can it be done in just 1 line?

```
my $fh_out = IO::File->new($target_file, 'w');
$fh_out->binmode(':utf8');
```

For reference, the script starts as follows:

```
use 5.020;
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
# code here
```

Comment: IO::File is useless. `open($fh, ...)` also creates handle blessed into IO::File

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can [do it in one line](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::File#open(-FILENAME,-IOLAYERS-)).

> open accepts one, two or three parameters. With one parameter, it is just a front end for the built-in open function. With two or three parameters, the first parameter is a filename that may include whitespace or other special characters, and the second parameter is the open mode, optionally followed by a file permission value.
>
> [...]
>
> If IO::File::open is given a mode that includes the : character, it passes all the three arguments to the three-argument open operator.

So you just do this.

```
my $fh_out = IO::File->new('/some/path', '>:utf8');
```

It is the same as your first `open` line because it gets passed through.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest to try out [Path::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/~dagolden/Path-Tiny-0.100/lib/Path/Tiny.pm). For example, to open and write out your file

```
use Path::Tiny;

path('/some/path')->spew_utf8(@data);
```

From the docs, on [spew, spew_raw, spew_utf8](http://search.cpan.org/~dagolden/Path-Tiny-0.100/lib/Path/Tiny.pm#spew,_spew_raw,_spew_utf8)

> Writes data to a file atomically.    [ ... ]
>   `spew_raw` is like `spew` with a binmode of `:unix` for a fast, unbuffered, raw write.
>
> `spew_utf8` is like `spew` with a `binmode` of `:unix:encoding(UTF-8)` (or [PerlIO::utf8_strict](http://search.cpan.org/~leont/PerlIO-utf8_strict-0.006/lib/PerlIO/utf8_strict.pm) ). If [Unicode::UTF8](http://search.cpan.org/~chansen/Unicode-UTF8-0.60/lib/Unicode/UTF8.pod) 0.58+ is installed, a raw spew will be done instead on the data encoded with `Unicode::UTF8`.

The module integrates many tools for handling files and directories, paths and content. It is often simple calls like above, but also method chaining, recursive directory iterator, hooks for callbacks, etc. There is error handling throughout, consistent and thoughtful dealing with edge cases, `flock` on input/ouput handles, its own tiny and useful class for exceptions ... see docs.

Answer (score -1):

**Edit:**
You could also use [File::Slurp](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Slurp) **if it was not discouraged to use**

e.g

```
use File::Slurp qw(write_file);

write_file( 'filename', {binmode => ':utf8'}, $buffer ) ;
```

> The first argument to write_file is the filename. The next argument is
>   an optional hash reference and it contains key/values that can modify
>   the behavior of write_file. The rest of the argument list is the data
>   to be written to the file.

**Some good reasons to not use?**

- [Not reliable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41037415/reliable-perl-encoding-with-fileslurp)
- Has some [bugs](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=File-Slurp)
- And as @ThisSuitIsBlackNot said [File::Slurp is broken and wrong](http://blogs.perl.org/users/leon_timmermans/2015/08/fileslurp-is-broken-and-wrong.html)

Comment: AFAIK, it is more or less abandoned module, with some problems.

Comment: @jm666 true, but even though widely used

Comment: [File::Slurp is broken and wrong](http://blogs.perl.org/users/leon_timmermans/2015/08/fileslurp-is-broken-and-wrong.html)

Comment: I edited my answer so whoever comes to read it, hopefully will be useful

Comment: I read that File::Slurper is now the way to go. But still, it's OT :)